# Check if char is written in \xHH notation

Tags: c, escaping, hex

I'm trying to escape this input `\x01\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc\xff` to this `\\x01\\xc3\\xa4\\xc3\\xb6\\xc3\\xbc\\xff` to print it out with `printf("%s",input)`. Generally I've to escape every kind of input and also escape sequences with \t, \n, etc...

To do this, I've written the following function:

```
void kvstr_escape_string(char* dest, const KV_Buffer* src)
{
char c;
int i = 0;
const char* data = src->data; // src->data is a char*

while (src != NULL && i < src->length && (c = *(data++))) {
    switch(c) {
        case '\a':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'a';
                break;
        case '\b':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'b';
                break;
        case '\t':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 't';
                break;
        case '\n':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'n';
                break;
        case '\v':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'v';
                break;
        case '\f':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'f';
                break;
        case '\r':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'r';
                break;
        case '\\':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                break;
        case '\"':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = '\"';
                break;
        case '\x01':
                *(dest++) = '\\';
                *(dest++) = 'x';
                *(dest++) = '0';
                *(dest++) = '1';
                break;
      // Here i need something to handle \xHH
        default:
                *(dest++) = c;
       }
       i++;
    }

    *(dest++) = '\0';
}
```

My problem is how can I handle all the different \xHH inputs as shown in my function in the case of `case '\x01':`? Should I use regex?

[Update] look at the answer from Karel. In case you are wondering how the default block should look like, here is an example:

```
default:
        if (c < 32 || c > 126){
            *(dest++) = '\\';
            *(dest++) = 'x';
            sprintf(d, "%.2x", c);
            *(dest++) = d[0];
            *(dest++) = d[1];
        }else{
            *(dest++) = c;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
case '\x01':
    *(dest++) = '\\';
    *(dest++) = 'x';
    *(dest++) = '0';
    *(dest++) = '1';
    break;
```

basically just is meant to match a literal byte with value 1. You could just as well write it as

```
case 1:
    ...
```

I would move this block into the `default` situation and match whether `c` is 31 or less (32 being a space). Also you might want to escape characters with an ASCII value larger than 126, the tilde. Off the top of my head:

```
default:
    if (c < 32 || c > 126)
        // add "\\x" followed by two hex digits of the value of c
    else
        // simply add the value of c
```

As for the conversion of a value to two hex characters, I'd use a small conversion buffer and `sprintf()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks, this is a good approach and I've thought about that. My problem is that I've to add "\\x" only if the input was "\x01" and not if the input is "1". Is there a possibility to check that?

Comment: @ManuelB. `case: '\x01'` is same as `case: 1`

Comment: Ok so let me explain better - if the input is "\x01" I should provide this output "\\x01", if the input is "1" the output should be "1". Is there any possibility to distinguish those two cases?

Comment: Umm you're almost on the right track ;-) There is a character representing a '1' (which is ASCII value 49, or hexadecimal notation 0x31, or string notation \x31), but there is also the literal ASCII value 1 (hexadecimal notation 0x01, string notation \x01) which is a non-printable character. So if your string has a \x01 in it, then you want to add to your output string: a backslash (denoted by "\\"), an x, a character that represents the printable zero, and then a printable 1. So for a \x01 in your string you'll be adding ASCII values 92, 120, 48 and 79.